# How to share Azure Datafactory self-hosted integration runtime for CI/CD managed ADF instances

Tags: azure-data-factory

Azure Datafactory tutorial(1) states the following:

> In CI/CD scenarios, the integration runtime (IR) type in different environments must be the same. For example, if you have a self-hosted IR in the development environment, the same IR must also be of type self-hosted in other environments, such as test and production. Similarly, if you're sharing integration runtimes across multiple stages, you have to configure the integration runtimes as linked self-hosted in all environments, such as development, test, and production.

If I use dev/test/prod environments like described in the tutorial with self-hosted integration runtime(SHIR) do I need to create an extra Azure Datafactory which is serving SHIR for CI/CD managed environments as a linked service?

(1) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/operationalize-azure-data-factory-pipelines/4-continuous-integration-deployment

Answer (score 1):

Yes, a separate data factory is needed whose role is to host the SHIR and share it to other data factories.  This is from a Microsoft support ticket I had with the same question.

In my case I had two ADFs provisioned, prod and non-prod, and wanted to share a multi-node SHIR with both.  I was unable share the one created on the non-prod ADF with the prod ADF like I was expecting.  MS said I needed a third to host the SHIR and share it to prod & non-prod ADFs.

Answer (score 0):

The same tutorial has the following extra best practices

> Integration runtimes and sharing. Integration runtimes don't change often and are similar across all stages in your CI/CD. So Data Factory expects you to have the same name and type of integration runtime across all stages of CI/CD. If you want to share integration runtimes across all stages, consider using a ternary factory just to contain the shared integration runtimes. You can use this shared factory in all of your environments as a linked integration runtime type.

**Other integration runtime related notes**

**Default Integration runtime**
It should be also noted that on `adf_publish` only some of the `Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/integrationRuntimes` resources are visible.

E.g. `AutoResolveIntegrationRuntime` when deployed without VNet support is not visible but Self-Hosted Integration runtimes are.

**Integration Runtime with Vnet support**
Current portal driven deployment template is using `vNetEnabled` to control if

- Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/managedVirtualNetworks
- Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/integrationRuntimes with name AutoResolveIntegrationRuntime and managedVirtualNetwork config is created

VNet enriched integrationRuntimes is present in the adf_publish/ARM export